# If God is an immaterial being, is it impossible for Him to exist?

Tags: theology, existence-of-god

Most people, even atheists, often at least recognize the possibility that God may exist but claim that it is very improbable.

But if God is defined as an immaterial being, is the notion of that even coherent? Is He dare I say impossible? When something is deemed to be logically impossible, it is unimaginable and leads to a contradiction.

Now in order to establish a contradiction in a phrase, the phrase must obviously first mean something. But in what sense can a being ever be immaterial? Can you imagine one? The very notion of a being seems to imply physicality. Even beings that seem to have “immaterial” experiences such as humans seem to have “materialness” pictured fundamentally within the concept. Can you imagine an immaterial human or is there always a physical component such as the human body that makes up that object in your imagination?

Strip a human being of all its physical parts and imagine it to immaterially exist. Can you? Many have argued that this can be done through the concept of a soul but in what sense would a soul exist? When imagining a soul, most, I bet would still imagine some sort of ghastly or ghostly figure that is ultimately material in the sense of it at least taking a form or some shape.

So, can one definitively say that an immaterial god, who has the powers that he is imagined to have, cannot exist?

Comment: Pick up a dictionary to play 20 questions with.  Half the nouns in there are not material objects.  Beauty?  It is an abstraction. The USSC?  It is an organizational institution, with neither location, nor fixed membership.  Pain?  what are its dimensions?     Doing self-questioning, before you bother posting a question to the rest of us, is a good idea.

Comment: The question says immaterial being, not immaterial concept. Beauty neither the USSC are beings. An immaterial concept is actually a redundant phrase since a concept by definition is immaterial. Reading the question before commenting is a good idea.

Comment: So are you saying only agents have "beingness"?  That strikes me as an unusual retro-fit to your question, beingness is generally held to apply to all sorts of non-agent items.  What your question simply boiled down to is what is "realism" and your inability to "imagine" anything being real other than matter.  Abstract objects, plus experiences, plus sociological inventions, are all well known and long discussed exceptions to this.  OR -- in your retro-fit, are you claiming that AGENCY needs materiality????  Why?  Alternatively, why not accept advice, rather than inventing rationalizations.

Comment: Again, you’re the one inventing rationalizations after purposefully or ignorantly not reading the question yourself. Secondly, as per the definition of a being when used in noun form: “a real or imaginary living creature or entity, especially an intelligent one.”

Comment: @thinkingman a lot of the time you claim that things are given "by definition" in some way, or are logically impossible, etc. but we know that there are other definitions and logical possibilities, we cite sources to said effect, and hardly anything ever comes of it. I know you said one time that you want to inspire discussion, but again, the SE isn't a forum, so we need to try to ask our questions in a more resolute way. I know that's hard with philosophy, but the reason it's hard should undermine your apparent overconfidence/dogmatism about things like possibility/probability, no?

Comment: For example, in response to this question of yours, I am tempted to quote Kant's discourse on apperception, which quote might be taken to both support *and* undercut your claims, here. Or I could cite objections to the meaningfulness of materialism itself. But what good would it do? How is the question answerable precisely enough to have an SE-acceptable answer?

Comment: Note that the argument that something cannot be the case because you cannot imagine it is explicitly the fallacy of argument from incredulity:  https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity

Comment: No the agreement is that a being implies physicality by definition

Comment: @Dcleve The USSC members is the extent that it physically exists, and I could point you to those. Beauty is, at best, an emergent property, but it's probably just a function of our minds. Pain is what your brain and body does in response to certain stimuli. If you want to argue for a god that's merely an abstract concept, that would be one thing, but the examples you gave wouldn't be all that relevant to a god that actually physically (but not physically) exists, that created us and wants a relationship with us, who cares about the fabric of the clothes we wear, and so forth.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- abstract objects are a useful can opener to assist physicalists see examples of existing things that are not physical.  Citing them as an example is to provide examples to demonstrate that Thinkingman is making a false claim.   Your extremely forced effort to recast abstractions as somehow material -- should give you pause.

Comment: He didn’t reframe abstractions as material. His point was that god isn’t just some idea. He is posited as an immaterial being that simultaneously manages to cause PHYSICAL effects. The USSC doesn’t cause anything. Members of the USSC do.

Answer (score 1):

An immaterial being cannot exist since the very notion of a being implies that the being must be physical, by definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "being" and "physical"? Is your meaning trivial or nontrivial (makes no difference or makes some specific difference)? Why do you think definitions have so much discursive power that they can settle substantive questions "just like that"?

Comment: One might, for example, conflate the concept of *substance* with the concept of matter, and it might be more plausible to suppose that *insubstantial* beings must not exist; but in fact the concept of substance is more general than that of matter (per usual word usage, anyway), so this reasoning would end up as an equivocation, here. And then belief in substance-property objects is not undeniable (c.f. Hume's "bundle theory" of objects).

Comment: If I answer what “being” means, you can further ask what my definition means to an infinite regress. Every debate ever would be hopelessly stuck on semantics if that were the case. I go by what most people mean by “being”, that is, an agent that is often intelligent. And one cannot imagine such a being as immaterial. Without a form or shape, in what way would the agent exist, much less do things? Any effect done on the physical world would have to be caused by a physical mechanism. How would an immaterial cause start something physical?

Comment: When we dynamically interpret zero-dimensional functions (e.g. [dimensionless constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_physical_constant) if I'm not mistaken), then we easily know about immaterial states, "causes," etc. I would advise against saying easily falsified things like "I go by what most people mean" seeing as *we* know that *you* do not.

Comment: From a quick google search, “a real or imaginary living creature or entity, especially an intelligent one.” So I do go by what most people mean.

Comment: "Being" is also a modification of "to be," which is cognate with "is," and has historically been used to refer to anything that exists, be it intelligent/conscious or not. In fact [a Google search for "being definition"](https://www.google.com/search?q=being+definition&rlz=1CABBMB_enUS991&oq=being+defi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l9.2594j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) lists existence as the first definition, then moves on to a reference to persons, the next two Google results on the first page start with the generic sense.

Comment: FWIW, the concept of persons, as per the word "person," depends, historically, very much on the sense attached to translated reformulations of "hypostasis" when *that* word was used to refer to the elements of the Christian Trinity, so even the definition of "being" in terms of persons has some deep roots in talk of an immaterial entity.

Comment: @KristianBerry +1 on setting aright the assumptions around 'being'.  To see how stuck the OP is in his Abrahamic assumptions, see the native American [God is not a noun](https://glennaparicioparry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Alford1994-God-Is-Not-A-Noun-in-Native-America.pdf) but [a verb](https://glennaparicioparry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Alford1994-God-is-a-Verb.pdf)

Comment: After above comment I'm happy to find the *God is a verb* meme in esoteric Judaism as well: [Kabbalah](https://www.spiritualityandpractice.com/book-reviews/view/767/god-is-a-verb)

Comment: Words have definitions. Definitions are determined by the majority. The majority of the world takes “being” to mean at the very least an agent. Using a word in a way that the majority of the world interprets it to mean is not an assumption

Answer (score 1):

God clearly does not exist in any sense with which we are empirically familiar.

Answer (score 1):

> Most people, even atheists, often at least recognize the possibility that God may exist but claim that it is very improbable.

What atheists recognize is that not everything is amenable to experimental study, particularly all the things non-physical. There is pretty strong evidence that the World was not created in seven days or that Humans and Monkeys evolved from the same common ancestor. But proving that there is no life after death is more challenging - we are just sure that this post-mortem existence is not physical. We simply cannot study anything that has no contact with our physical world, and hence we can neither confirm nor deny existence of non-physical world. This is when scientists usually follow the Occam's razor suggests that we can ignore whatever is non-physical for all the practical purposes. God, as understood by modern religions (at least those that are not in outright denial of scientific facts) belongs to the realm of such *unprovable and undisprovable things*.

In this sense, **scientists do not "recognize the possibility that God may exist" or assign any probability to it - they mostly do not care and/or do not mind others believing and/or do not mix their personal beliefs and their research.** Atheists are those who actively believe that God does not exist in any non-physical way, or more frequently simply those who object the claims that God may have any physical influence.

On the other hand, one could claim that God exists as an idea in human society. The belief in God is certainly documented in many texts, passed from generation to generation, and has great influence on the mankind - wars continue to be fought in the name of God, sacrifices continue to be made in his name, and many other things happen. This existence is *immaterial* in the sense that this God is not a distinct being. But it is physical in the sense that it depends on a physical carrier - in the same sense as the information store in a computer memory exists only as long as the computer itself exists.

Comment: @Rushi thanks! Fixed.

Comment: It's probably better to say *science* doesn't say anything about God (at least if you're talking about a god who has no detectable influence in the material world). Because scientists consists of plenty of both atheists and theists, who do care about the topic (and also others who don't).

Comment: @NotThatGuy I modified the sentence that you are probably referring to. The point is that a scientist's belief in God is not involved in their research work - one could mention here all kinds of academic institutions associated with the Catholic church, as well as those who are practicing religion for traditional reasons.

Comment: Evolution and neuroscience has arguably gone a long way towards disproving life after death. If we can trace and explain our origins going back to single-celled organisms, and we understand both the low-level structure of the brain, as well as the high-level functions, and brain injuries and disease can fundamentally change someone's personality, it gets quite difficult to fit any sort of transcendent existence in there (that may still be compatible with some convoluted imaginings of an afterlife, but those wouldn't be all that compelling).

Comment: @NotThatGuy we cannot test experimentally that no immaterial activity happens after death - it is beyond science, and it really doesn't matter. Regarding the rest - you ignore the *emergence* - the properties of a big system may not be predictable from those of the elements constituting it.

Comment: I would argue that an immaterial being causing a physical effect is impossible. This is because in order to cause a physical effect, one must convert an immaterial source into a physical effect, but this can’t happen without a physical source such as the case of me making a decision to move my hand. In the case of god, many have often claimed that he is completely immaterial while simultaneously being able to cause physical effects on the world. So I actually DO think we can firmly deny even the possibility of this kind of being’s existence. God as a being must be physical if He exists.

Comment: @thinkingman not sure what you say: beings that do not cause physical effects cannot be studied scientifically - hence we cannot say anything about them. I already said it in my answer. Human ideas however can cause real physical effects - I addressed this as well.